# How can i mock underscorejs in unit testing? [angularjs]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I added underscore as a module to my application.
I'm doing unit testing now and i don't know how i can mock underscorejs.

**underscorejs module**

```
var underscore = angular.module('underscore', []);
  underscore.factory('_', function () {
    // assumes underscore has already been loaded on the page
    return window._;
});
```

**unit test**

This works but i don't want to implement every underscore feature... Is there another way to use underscorejs?

```
    $provide.factory('_', function () {
        var und = {};
        und.findWhere = function () {

        };
        return und;
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it can be done:

**Step 1:** Inject the service in the before Each function.

**Step 2:** Then we need to mockup the underscore service,
So write:

```
spyOn(underscoreService,"methodName").and.callFake(function(){
return //whatever you want;
})
```

**OR**

```
  spyOn(underscoreService,"methodName").and.callThrough()
```

I hope this works for you!

Comment: i'm not sure i understood. Basically methodName would be for example the findWhere method from underscorejs? But than again i need to write the findWhere function myself and it's execution.

Comment: Step 1 :beforeEach(module('underscore'));
Step 2 : Where do i mock it ? And how?
This does not work
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller){
      spyOn(underscore, 'findWhere').and.callThrough();
}));

Comment: had a typo in my karma file which didn't load underscore -_- that was the reason.